# CSS reform ASCI image

Tags: css

How do I make an ASCII image fly out and re-form?

```
.fly-in-text {list-style: none;
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);}
            .fly-in-text li {margin-right: 50px;
                transition: all 2.5s ease;}
            .fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(1) { transform: translateX(-200px) translateY(-200px); }

       <div><ul class="fly-in-text hidden" onclick="play()">
            <li>.-"-.</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: *fly out and re-form* ?

Comment: The text flies in. I would like it to fly out (leave the screen) and then repeat the shape (or loop, I guess). Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely not a [MCVE]. Please post one and we can help you.

Comment: Not enough space. But I will try